# can anyone explain me this(hackerrank problem) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime as dt


fmt = '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
for i in range(int(input())):
    print(int(abs((dt.strptime(input(), fmt) - dt.strptime(input(), fmt)).total_seconds())))
```

Comment: Looks like you enter a number of iterations. Then enter 2 datetimes in the given format. Then it prints the difference between the 2 times in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you enter a number - that's how many timestamp pairs you'll be asked to enter.

Then, you enter those timestamps, one at a time. They must be in the same format, as defined by `fmt`: weekday day month year hour:minute:second timezone - for example: Fri, 6 Mar 2020 19:06:06 CET.

For every pair of timestamps, the difference between them (in seconds) is computed and printed.